# Count the length of each event by group

Tags: r, count

I am counting the events with multiple conditions and my final result is represented for each year seperately. The example of my df:

```
year <- c(rep(1981,20))
k1 <- c(rep(NA,5),rep("COLD",4),rep(NA,4),"COLD",NA,"COLD",rep(NA,4))
k2 <- c(rep(NA,10),rep("COLD",2),rep(NA,8))
k3 <- c(rep(NA,3),"COLD",rep(NA,16))
k4 <- c(rep(NA,3),rep("COLD",5),rep(NA,2),rep("COLD",6),NA,rep("COLD",3))
k5 <- c(rep(NA,3),"COLD",rep(NA,3),"COLD",rep(NA,3),"COLD",rep(NA,8))

df <- data.frame(year,k1,k2,k3,k4,k5)
```

The code I use is below:

```r
rle_col <-  function(k_col) {
         with(rle(is.na(k_col)), {
         i1 <- values
         i1[values & lengths <= 2] <- 'Invalid'
         sum(!values & lengths >= 5 & 
                 (lead(i1) != "Invalid" & lag(i1)>=1), na.rm = TRUE)
         
     })
 }

rezult <- df %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarise(across(starts_with('k'), rle_col))
```

My code works well, but I need to get one more variable - the length of each event (or the number of members in each event). This means that instead of sum here  `sum(!values & lengths >= 5 & (lead(i1) != "Invalid" & lag(i1)>=1), na.rm = TRUE)` I need to get the number of values within each event, which satisfies these conditions.  Is it possible? Thank you for any help.
The result I would like to see should be as follows:

```
Year  k4
1981  5
1981  10
```

Comment: (1) Perhaps I'm too tired at the moment, but I don't even understand why your code works. What is the definition of `values`? (2) Did I understand you right: You want to count the consecutive "COLD" values, but only, if there are five or more per "group"?

Comment: Yes, I need to find all events with 5 or more consecutive "COLD" values and this event is counted as the event, only if there are more than 2 NA after the event and one NA before the event. But I need also to know the length of each event, e.g. are there 5, 6, or 15 consecutive "COLD" values.

Comment: Did you mean 2 or more `NA` _ before_  the event? If it is _ after_  the event, k4's event with 6 consecutive "COLD"s doesn't count.

Comment: You are right, it was my mistake. It should be 10 instead 6. If the lead is less than 3 it is the same event and counts as one, even if there are some NA in-between. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have to be easy solutions for this problem. Here is a ridiculous complicated (and not well performing) approach using `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map_df(
  names(df)[grepl("^k", names(df))],
  ~df %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    mutate(
      grp = (!!sym(.x) == "COLD" & !is.na(!!sym(.x))) | 
        !(is.na(lead(!!sym(.x))) | is.na(lag(!!sym(.x))))
      ) %>% 
    group_by(year, grp2 = cumsum(!grp)) %>% 
    filter(grp) %>% 
    count(name = .x) %>% 
    filter(!!sym(.x) >= 5) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(-grp2)
)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 6
   year    k1    k2    k3    k4    k5
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1  1981    NA    NA    NA     5    NA
2  1981    NA    NA    NA    10    NA
```

Issues:

- It's not performing well.
- If there are several groups in different columns the output looks like this:

```r
# A tibble: 9 x 6
   year    k1    k2    k3    k4    k5
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1  1981     4    NA    NA    NA    NA
2  1981     3    NA    NA    NA    NA
3  1981    NA     2    NA    NA    NA
4  1981    NA    NA     1    NA    NA
5  1981    NA    NA    NA     5    NA
6  1981    NA    NA    NA    10    NA
7  1981    NA    NA    NA    NA     1
8  1981    NA    NA    NA    NA     1
9  1981    NA    NA    NA    NA     1
```

At the moment I don't know how to change it into something like

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 6
    year    k1    k2    k3    k4    k5
   <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1  1981     4     2     1     5     1
 2  1981     3    NA    NA    10     1
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Better than I expected. Thank you, @Martin_Gal! I found the final result easy to use for my further tasks. Running this code for the first time I got an error message "Error in count(., name = .x) : unused argument (name = .x)", but I restarted RStudio and now everything is ok.